# Finding the value of $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^3} \int_0^x\frac{t\ln(1+t)}{t^4+4}dt$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

I have to find this :

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^3} \int_0^x\frac{t\ln(1+t)}{t^4+4}dt$$

But I don't know how to proceed. First I thought of using Leibnitz theorem but it is used for differentiation of definite integral having limits as a function of another variable. So it is of no use here, I guess. So how should I proceed?

Any answer to this problem will be appreciated by me.

Comment: See also: [Find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac {1}{x^3}\int_0^x \frac{t\ln (1+t)}{t^4+4}\mathrm{d}t $ without using L'hopital's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using L'Hospital rule given limit becomes:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x \ln(1+x)}{3x^2(x^4+4)}
=\frac{1}{12}$$ 
$ $

Comment: You really thought that we would not notice your scheme?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that both the numerator and the denominator tends to 0 as $x \to 0$.

You can use L'Hôpital's rule, and then the numerator's derivative is...

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 
$$\frac{t \ln(1+t)}{t^4+4} = \frac{t^2}{4} + O(t^3).$$